# Change the Round Rect Button to a Rectangular Button with no curved corners in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, interface-builder, uibutton

Hey guys,
Need a help in Interface Builder. Usually when you insert a button, it's settings is a Round Rect Button. How do we change the Round Rect Button into a Rectangular Button? Like I don't want the curved corners of the button, just regular pointy corners like a rectangular shape? Hope someone can help me with this easy question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you have to do is give it a background in inspector. Or you could assign it an image.

Answer (score 2):

in xcode 4.5 i use:-

```
[[myButton layer] setCornerRadius:0.0];
[[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:1];
```